# webpage redirects in IE, Chrome... not Firefox?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

With firebug, grab the HTTP headers.. firefox gives 200 OK status.

Firebug in Chrome, tells me it is a 301 redirect.

The problem is that the page is not supposed to redirect. The htaccess only forces WWW..

Help!

Comment: can you post the relevant part of the .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

That kind of .htaccess rule *works* by redirecting the request!  The `R=301` at the end means "redirect, sending http status `301`"

btw the rule you have will redirect *www.example.com* to *example.com*.   Perhaps you want the opposite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The WWW / non WWW isn't an issue, it is set up as a hack for some script. Not the best idea, but it works for what it needs to.

The issue is that http://website.com is forwarding to http://website.com/sub-page in IE and Chrome. 

There is no redirect set up that tells it to go to this sub, not in WHM, not at the dotcom. 

I apologize for the poor explanation initially

Comment: Ah, OK.  I would guess Firefox skips the redirect after the first time because http status `301` means "moved permanently". Firefox must be remembering that fact.